# Две програмы соединить в одну

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyqt, многомерные-списки

У меня есть программа, в которой **`15`** вопросов, и вторая с другими 15 вопросами. 
Я хочу эти вопросы, варианты ответа и ответ поместить в одну программу. 
Вернее в игре так и останется 15 вопросов, просто на **`1`** вопрос выбирать рандомно из двух, 
и на второй тоже рандомно из двух и т.д.

И варианты ответа к каждому вопросу свои.

Код первой программы:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import webbrowser
import random 


class WindowGroup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName('windowgroup')

        self.list_questions = [                  
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Що мають на увазі кажучи: "пройшов вогонь, воду і мідні труби"?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який материк найбільший?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Куди вказує червона стрілка компаса?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який пігмент забарвлює листя в зелений колір?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який препарат марно намагалися отримати середньовічні алхіміки?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Як правильно кликати гусака?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Якій кухні належить блюдо "форшмак"?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Яку рослину називають «живим світлофором»?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Що є туманністю Андромеди?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Назвіть офіційну мову Шрі-Ланки:</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Столицею якої країни є місто Богота?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Які літальні апарати конструював Отто Ліліенталь?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У якому столітті в Китаї почали добувати залізо?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У якій мові програмування немає засобів роботи з файлами?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У яких тварин офіційно реєструвалися сонячні удари, подібні до людських?</h1>',
        ]

        self.quantity_questions = len(self.list_questions) 

        self.list_buttons = [                                     
            ['A: Навчання', 'В: Самогон', 'C: Стаж', 'D: Досвід'],
            ['A: Північна Америка', 'В: Південна Америка', 'C: Африка', 'D: Євразія'],
            ['A: Північ', 'В: Схід', 'C: Захід', 'D: Південь'],
            ['A: Каротин', 'В: Антоціан', 'C: Хлорофіл', 'D: Танін'],
            ['A: Настоянку мудрості', 'В: Засіб від лупи', 'C: Еліксир життя', 'D: Напій сміливості'],
            ['A: Киць-киць', 'В: Гуль-гуль', 'C: Тега-тега', 'D: Курчат-курчат'],
            ['A: Єврейській', 'В: Грузинській', 'C: Китайській', 'D: Індійській'],
            ['A: Акаліфа', 'В: Медуниця', 'C: Маранта', 'D: Кротон'],
            ['A: Метеорит', 'В: Зірка', "С: Сузір'я", 'D: Галактика'],
            ['A: Урду', 'В: Сінгальский', 'C: Бенгальський', 'D: Брахми'],
            ['A: Чилі', 'В: Перу' ,'C: Аргентина', 'D: Колумбія'],
            ['A: Вертольоти', 'В: Дирижаблі', 'C: Літаки-біплани', 'D: Планери'],
            ['A: 4 вік до н.е', 'В: 2 вік', 'C: 3 вік', 'D: 5 вік до н.е.'],
            ['A: PHP', 'В: Delphi', 'C: C++', 'D: JavaScript'],
            ['A: У собак', 'В: У кішок', 'C: У свиней', 'D: У кроликів']
        ]
        self.list_yes_buttons = [                      
            'D: Досвід',
            'D: Євразія',
            'D: Південь',
            'C: Хлорофіл',
            'C: Еліксир життя',
            'C: Тега-тега',
            'A: Єврейській',
            'В: Медуниця',
            'D: Галактика',
            'В: Сінгальский',
            'D: Колумбія',
            'D: Планери',
            'D: 5 вік до н.е.',
            'D: JavaScript',
            'D: У кроликів'
        ]
        self.current_question = 0 

        self.label = QLabel(self.list_questions[self.current_question])

        self.radioGroupBox = QGroupBox('') 
        self.radioGroup = QButtonGroup() 

        self.rbtn_1 = QPushButton('A: Навчання')
        self.rbtn_1.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_2 = QPushButton('В: Самогон')
        self.rbtn_2.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_3 = QPushButton('C: Стаж')
        self.rbtn_3.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_4 = QPushButton('D: Досвід')
        self.rbtn_4.setFixedSize(740, 49) 

        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_1)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_2)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_3)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_4)

        self.hint_5050 = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_5050.setIcon(QIcon('5050_normal.png'))
        self.hint_5050.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_5050.setFixedSize(120, 100)

        self.hint_audience = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_audience.setIcon(QIcon('audience_normal.png'))
        self.hint_audience.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_audience.setFixedSize(120, 100)

        self.hint_expert = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_expert.setIcon(QIcon('expert_normal.png'))
        self.hint_expert.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_expert.setFixedSize(120, 100)      

        self.hint_switch = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_switch.setIcon(QIcon('switch_2_normal.png'))
        self.hint_switch.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_switch.setFixedSize(120, 100)         

        layout_ans1 = QHBoxLayout()  
        layout_ans2 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_ans3 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_ans2.addWidget(self.rbtn_1) 
        layout_ans2.addWidget(self.rbtn_2)
        layout_ans3.addWidget(self.rbtn_3) 
        layout_ans3.addWidget(self.rbtn_4)

        layout_ans1.addLayout(layout_ans2)
        layout_ans1.addLayout(layout_ans3) 

        self.radioGroupBox.setLayout(layout_ans1)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.radioGroupBox)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                                  
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName('centralWidget')          
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)  

        self.dict_audience_img = { 
            "A": "audience_A.png", 
            "B": "audience_B.png",
            "C": "audience_C.png",
            "D": "audience_D.png",
        }

        self.num = 3

        self.question = QLabel('<h1 style="color: rgb(250, 55, 55);">Правила гри')

        self.rules = QLabel('''Гра "Хто хоче стати мільйонером?" 
\
Ви повинні правильно відповісти на низку питань \
з кількома варіантами відповідей, щоб заробити 3.000.000 грн. \
Всього 15 питань, кожне питання коштує певної суми грошей, \
учасники не мають жодних тимчасових обмежень для надання \
відповіді. Учасник також отримуює 4 види підказок, щоб допомогти собі, \
якщо вони застрягли на конкретному питанні.  
\
Більше ознайомитися з правилами можна, натиснувши на кнопку. 
\
Хай щастить!''')
        self.rules.setStyleSheet("""
        font: bold;
        color: rgb(185, 255, 0);
    """)
        self.rules.setFixedSize(1010,450)
        self.rules.setObjectName('rules')
        self.rules.setWordWrap(True)    

        self.button_rules = QPushButton('Правила')
        self.button_rules.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open('https://ru.wwbm.com/rules'))
        self.button_rules.setFixedSize(300,50)

        self.button_start = QPushButton('Почати', clicked=self._start)  
        self.button_start.setFixedSize(300,50)
        
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.lineH1 = QHBoxLayout()
        lineH2 = QHBoxLayout()
        lineH3 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lineH1.addWidget(self.question, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        lineH2.addWidget(self.rules)
        lineH3.addWidget(self.button_rules, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        lineH3.addWidget(self.button_start, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.lineH1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.rules, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.layout.addLayout(lineH3)
        
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_timer)

        self.windowGroup = WindowGroup()

        self.windowGroup.rbtn_1.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.windowGroup.rbtn_2.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.windowGroup.rbtn_3.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.windowGroup.rbtn_4.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.list_rbtn = [
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_1,
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_2,
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_3,
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_4,
        ] 
        self.correct_answer = '<h1 style="color: #4E9F3D;">Це вірна відповідь!</h1>'
        self.wrong_answer = '<h1 style="color: #DA0037;">Це НЕ вірна відповідь!</h1>'

        self.windowGroup.hint_5050.clicked.connect(self.clicked_5050)

        self.windowGroup.hint_audience.clicked.connect(self.clicked_audience)

    def on_clicked(self):
        self.windowGroup.setEnabled(False)
        sender = self.sender()  
        self.sender_click = sender

        if sender.text() in self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons:
            sender.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                f'{self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question]} \
                {self.correct_answer}' 
            )                 
        else:
            sender.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;") 
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                f'{self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question]} \
                {self.wrong_answer}' 
            )         
            self.windowGroup.current_question = self.windowGroup.quantity_questions
            self.num = 3    
        self.windowGroup.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.third)  

    def set_stylesheet(self):  
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel, QPushButton {
                font-size: 20pt;
            }
            #rules { 
                background-color: #ccffbd;
            }
            #windowgroup > QLabel { 
                font-size: 11pt;
            }
            #windowgroup > QGroupBox { 
                background-color: #a44500;
                font-size: 20pt;
                width: 620px; height: 49px;
            }
            QPushButton {
                background-color: #D98C00;
                font-size: 34px;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: #0082fc;
                border: 2px solid #FFA6D5;
            }
            #centralWidget {
                background-image: url(first.jpg);
            }
            #window_audience {
                backround-image: url(first.jpg);
            }
            """) 
        
    def update_timer(self):        
        self.question.setText(f'<h1 style="color: rgb(250, 55, 55);">{self.num}</h1>')
        if self.num == 0:
            self.timer.stop()
            
            self.set_stylesheet()                 

            self.question.setPixmap(QPixmap("million.png"))
            self.num = 3
            self.rules.hide()
            self.button_start.hide()
            self.button_rules.hide()
            self.layout.addWidget(self.windowGroup, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

            self.lineH1.insertStretch(0)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(1, self.windowGroup.hint_5050)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(2)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(3, self.windowGroup.hint_audience)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(4)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(-1)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(-1, self.windowGroup.hint_expert)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(-1)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(-1, self.windowGroup.hint_switch)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(-1)

            return            
        self.num -= 1        

    def _start(self):
        self.timer.start(1000)     

    def third(self):
        self.windowGroup.setEnabled(True)  
        self.windowGroup.hint_5050.setEnabled(False)      
        
        if self.windowGroup.current_question + 1 < self.windowGroup.quantity_questions:

            self.windowGroup.current_question += 1
            
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question])
            
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_1.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][0])
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_2.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][2])
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_3.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][1])
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_4.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][3])                
            
            self.set_stylesheet()            
        else:
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                '<h1 style="color: #FFDD93;">Гру закінчено, дякуємо за участь!</h1>'
            )             
            self.windowGroup.setEnabled(False)
            self.sender_click.setStyleSheet(
                "background-color: #D98C00; width: 780px; height: 49px;")
            self.set_stylesheet() 
            
        for rbtn in self.list_rbtn:    
            rbtn.setEnabled(True)
            rbtn.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton {
                    background-color: #D98C00; 
                    width: 620px; height: 49px;
                }
                QPushButton:hover {
                    background-color: #0082fc;
                    border: 2px solid #FFA6D5;
                }
            """)
            
        self.windowGroup.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)   

    def clicked_5050(self):
        self.windowGroup.hint_5050.setEnabled(False)
        
        current_question = self.windowGroup.current_question
        list_yes_buttons = self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[current_question]
        list_5050 = [list_yes_buttons,]
        
        not_buttons = self.windowGroup.list_buttons[current_question]
        not_buttons.remove(list_yes_buttons)
        not_buttons = random.choices(not_buttons)

        list_5050.append(not_buttons[0])
        
        for rbtn in self.list_rbtn:
            if rbtn.text() in list_5050:
                pass
            else:
                rbtn.setEnabled(False)

        
    def clicked_audience(self):
        self.windowGroup.hint_audience.setEnabled(False)
        litter_yes = self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[
            self.windowGroup.current_question][0]
        img = self.dict_audience_img[litter_yes]
        
        self.audience_messageBox(img)
        
    def audience_messageBox(self, img):        
        window_audience = QMessageBox(self)
        window_audience.setWindowIcon(QIcon("audience_normal.png"))
        window_audience.setWindowTitle('Допомога зали') 

        window_audience.setIconPixmap(
            QPixmap(img).scaled(700, 700, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            )
        window_audience.exec_()   
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet("""
        QLabel {
            font-size: 20pt;
        }
        QPushButton { 
            font-size: 20pt;
            background-color: #ff8000;
        }
        #centralWidget {
            background-image: url(first.jpg);
        }
        #centeralMessage {
            backround-image: url(first.jpg);
        }
    """)
    w = MainWindow()          
    w.setWindowTitle('Million')  
    w.resize(1700, 770)
    w.move(125, 110)
    w.show()                           
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Код второй программы:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import webbrowser
import random 
import time


class WindowGroup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName('windowgroup')

        self.list_questions = [                  
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Як прізвище першого Президента України?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Як називають людину, що вважає за краще проводити вільний час дома?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Скільки лап у павука?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Хто на питання лорда Баскервіля "Що це"? відповіB: "Вівсянка, сер"?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Хто винайшов електричну лампочку?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У автомобілів який з цих країн міжнародний реєстраційний знак PL?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який режисер зняв фільм "Політ над гніздом зозулі"?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Що виділяють бугорки на язиці кішки, коли вона умивається?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Якого троянського царевича убив Ахіл?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Яка столиця Іраку?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Столицею якої країни є місто Антананаріву?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Як називається кругла за формою картина або рельєф?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Знаменита українська фехтувальниця?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У якій мові програмування немає засобів роботи з файлами?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">На якій відстані людина може відчути запах скунса?</h1>'
        ]

        self.quantity_questions = len(self.list_questions) 

        self.list_buttons = [                                     
            ['A: Ющенко', 'B: Кравчук', 'C: Кравченко', 'D: Кучма'],
            ['A: Домосід', 'B: Квартирний злодій', 'C: Домочадець', 'D: Домовий'],
            ['A: 4', 'B: 8', 'C: 3', 'D: 6'],
            ['A: Беломор', 'B: Блэкмор', 'C: Бэррімор', 'D: Берліоз'],
            ['A: Томас Едісон', 'B: Олександр Белл', 'C: Сер Джозеф Суон', 'D: Карл Бенц'],
            ['A: Польща', 'B: Нікарагуа', 'C: Нідерланди', 'D: Новій Зеландії'],
            ['A: Милош Форман', 'B: Роман Поланскі', 'C: Кшиштоф Кеслевский', 'D: Анджей Вайда'],
            ['A: Кадаревін', 'B: Кератин', 'C: Альбумін', 'D: Лецитін'],
            ['A: Гектор', 'B: Одісей', 'C: Паріс', 'D: Еней'],
            ['A: Аддис-Абеба', 'B: Багдад', 'C: Кабул', 'D: Тегеран'],
            ['A: Мадагаскар', 'B: Марокко', 'C: Мозамбік', 'D: Ангола'],
            ['A: Картуш', 'B: Тондо', 'C: Рондо', 'D: Плафон'],
            ['A: Ольга Харлан', 'B: Олеся Стефанко', 'C: Людмила Мілевич', 'D: Вікторія Сюмар'],
            ['A: JavaScript', 'B: PHP', 'C: C++', 'D: Delphi'],
            ['A: 2 км', 'B: 1,5 км', 'C: 1 км', 'D: 500 м'],
        ]
        self.list_yes_buttons = [                      
            'B: Кравчук',
            'A: Домосід',
            'B: 8',
            'C: Бэррімор',
            'A: Томас Едісон',
            'A: Польща',
            'A: Милош Форман',
            'B: Кератин',
            'A: Гектор',
            'B: Багдад',
            'A: Мадагаскар',
            'B: Тондо',
            'A: Ольга Харлан',
            'A: JavaScript',
            'B: 1,5 км',
        ]
        self.current_question = 0 

        self.label = QLabel(self.list_questions[self.current_question])

        self.radioGroupBox = QGroupBox('') 
        self.radioGroup = QButtonGroup() 

        self.rbtn_1 = QPushButton('A: Ющенко')
        self.rbtn_1.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_2 = QPushButton('C: Кравченко')
        self.rbtn_2.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_3 = QPushButton('B: Кравчук')
        self.rbtn_3.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_4 = QPushButton('D: Кучма')
        self.rbtn_4.setFixedSize(740, 49)
```

Я не могу ввести больше, потому что нельзя, но там идёт всё точно также как и в прошлой программею

Эти две програмы отличаются только вопросами, вариантами ответов и ответами, а код у них весь одинаковый!!!

Файлы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не надо объединять две программы. Вам надо вместо списков вопросов, ответов и правильных ответов - сделать [**Многомерные списки**](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&oq=python%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i57.23801j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Почитайте об этом.

Я вставил первые ТРИ вопроса, ответа и правильных ответа, остальные внесете самостоятельно по аналогии с первыми тремя.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import webbrowser
import random 


class WindowGroup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName('windowgroup')

        self.list_questions = [                  
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Що мають на увазі кажучи: "пройшов вогонь, воду і мідні труби"?</h1>',
             '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Як прізвище першого Президента України?</h1>',],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який материк найбільший?</h1>',
             '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Як називають людину, що вважає за краще проводити вільний час дома?</h1>',],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Куди вказує червона стрілка компаса?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Скільки лап у павука?</h1>',],
            
# !!! вставьте дальше остальные вопросы из вашей второй программы, по аналогии см.выше           
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який пігмент забарвлює листя в зелений колір?</h1>',
            ],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який препарат марно намагалися отримати середньовічні алхіміки?</h1>',
            ],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Як правильно кликати гусака?</h1>',
            ],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Якій кухні належить блюдо "форшмак"?</h1>',
            ],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Яку рослину називають «живим світлофором»?</h1>',
            ],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Що є туманністю Андромеди?</h1>',
            ],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Назвіть офіційну мову Шрі-Ланки:</h1>',
            ],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Столицею якої країни є місто Богота?</h1>',
            ],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Які літальні апарати конструював Отто Ліліенталь?</h1>',
            ],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У якому столітті в Китаї почали добувати залізо?</h1>',
            ],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У якій мові програмування немає засобів роботи з файлами?</h1>',
            ],
            ['<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У яких тварин офіційно реєструвалися сонячні удари, подібні до людських?</h1>',
            ],
        ]
# !!!                                                    
#        self.quantity_questions = len(self.list_questions) 
        self.quantity_questions = 15

        self.list_buttons = [                                     
            [['A: Навчання', 'В: Самогон', 'C: Стаж', 'D: Досвід'],
             ['A: Ющенко', 'B: Кравчук', 'C: Кравченко', 'D: Кучма'],
            ],
            [['A: Північна Америка', 'В: Південна Америка', 'C: Африка', 'D: Євразія'],
             ['A: Домосід', 'B: Квартирний злодій', 'C: Домочадець', 'D: Домовий'],
            ],
            
            [['A: Північ', 'В: Схід', 'C: Захід', 'D: Південь'],
             ['A: 4', 'B: 8', 'C: 3', 'D: 6'],
            ],
            
# !!! вставьте дальше остальные ответы из вашей второй программы, по аналогии см.выше           
            [['A: Каротин', 'В: Антоціан', 'C: Хлорофіл', 'D: Танін'],
            ],
            [['A: Настоянку мудрості', 'В: Засіб від лупи', 'C: Еліксир життя', 'D: Напій сміливості'],
            ],
            [['A: Киць-киць', 'В: Гуль-гуль', 'C: Тега-тега', 'D: Курчат-курчат'],
            ],
            [['A: Єврейській', 'В: Грузинській', 'C: Китайській', 'D: Індійській'],
            ],
            [['A: Акаліфа', 'В: Медуниця', 'C: Маранта', 'D: Кротон'],
            ],
            [['A: Метеорит', 'В: Зірка', "С: Сузір'я", 'D: Галактика'],
            ],
            [['A: Урду', 'В: Сінгальский', 'C: Бенгальський', 'D: Брахми'],
            ],
            [['A: Чилі', 'В: Перу' ,'C: Аргентина', 'D: Колумбія'],
            ],
            [['A: Вертольоти', 'В: Дирижаблі', 'C: Літаки-біплани', 'D: Планери'],
            ],
            [['A: 4 вік до н.е', 'В: 2 вік', 'C: 3 вік', 'D: 5 вік до н.е.'],
            ],
            [['A: PHP', 'В: Delphi', 'C: C++', 'D: JavaScript'],
            ],
            [['A: У собак', 'В: У кішок', 'C: У свиней', 'D: У кроликів']
            ],
        ]
        self.list_yes_buttons = [                      
            ['D: Досвід', 'B: Кравчук',],
            ['D: Євразія', 'A: Домосід',],
            ['D: Південь', 'B: 8',],

# !!! вставьте дальше остальные правильные ответы из вашей второй программы, по аналогии см.выше             
            ['C: Хлорофіл', ],
            ['C: Еліксир життя', ],
            ['C: Тега-тега', ],
            ['A: Єврейській', ],
            ['В: Медуниця', ],
            ['D: Галактика', ],
            ['В: Сінгальский', ],
            ['D: Колумбія', ],
            ['D: Планери', ],
            ['D: 5 вік до н.е.', ],
            ['D: JavaScript', ],
            ['D: У кроликів' ],
        ]
        
        self.current_question = 0 
        
# +++ vvv вставил две строки       
        self.current_question_text = random.choices(self.list_questions[0])[0]    
        self.current_question_index = self.list_questions[0].\
            index(self.current_question_text)
        #print(f'{self.current_question_index} == {self.current_question_text}') 
        
# !!!
#        self.label = QLabel(self.list_questions[self.current_question])
        self.label = QLabel(self.current_question_text)                   # +++

        self.radioGroupBox = QGroupBox('') 
        self.radioGroup = QButtonGroup() 

# !!!
#        self.rbtn_1 = QPushButton('A: Навчання')
# +++ vvv
        self.rbtn_1 = QPushButton( 
            self.list_buttons[self.current_question][self.current_question_index][0])
        self.rbtn_1.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_2 = QPushButton(
            self.list_buttons[self.current_question][self.current_question_index][1])
        self.rbtn_2.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_3 = QPushButton(
            self.list_buttons[self.current_question][self.current_question_index][2])
        self.rbtn_3.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_4 = QPushButton(
            self.list_buttons[self.current_question][self.current_question_index][3])
        self.rbtn_4.setFixedSize(740, 49) 
# +++ ^^^

        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_1)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_2)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_3)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_4)

        self.hint_5050 = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_5050.setIcon(QIcon('5050_normal.png'))
        self.hint_5050.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_5050.setFixedSize(120, 100)

        self.hint_audience = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_audience.setIcon(QIcon('audience_normal.png'))
        self.hint_audience.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_audience.setFixedSize(120, 100)

        self.hint_expert = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_expert.setIcon(QIcon('expert_normal.png'))
        self.hint_expert.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_expert.setFixedSize(120, 100)      

        self.hint_switch = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_switch.setIcon(QIcon('switch_2_normal.png'))
        self.hint_switch.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_switch.setFixedSize(120, 100)         

        layout_ans1 = QHBoxLayout()  
        layout_ans2 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_ans3 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_ans2.addWidget(self.rbtn_1) 
        layout_ans2.addWidget(self.rbtn_2)
        layout_ans3.addWidget(self.rbtn_3) 
        layout_ans3.addWidget(self.rbtn_4)

        layout_ans1.addLayout(layout_ans2)
        layout_ans1.addLayout(layout_ans3) 

        self.radioGroupBox.setLayout(layout_ans1)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.radioGroupBox)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                                  
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName('centralWidget')          
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)  

        self.dict_audience_img = { 
            "A": "audience_A.png", 
            "B": "audience_B.png",
            "C": "audience_C.png",
            "D": "audience_D.png",
        }
        self.num = 3
        self.question = QLabel('<h1 style="color: rgb(250, 55, 55);">Правила гри')
        self.rules = QLabel('''Гра "Хто хоче стати мільйонером?" 
\
Ви повинні правильно відповісти на низку питань \
з кількома варіантами відповідей, щоб заробити 3.000.000 грн. \
Всього 15 питань, кожне питання коштує певної суми грошей, \
учасники не мають жодних тимчасових обмежень для надання \
відповіді. Учасник також отримуює 4 види підказок, щоб допомогти собі, \
якщо вони застрягли на конкретному питанні.  
\
Більше ознайомитися з правилами можна, натиснувши на кнопку. 
\
Хай щастить!''')
        self.rules.setStyleSheet("""
        font: bold;
        color: rgb(185, 255, 0);
    """)
        self.rules.setFixedSize(1010,450)
        self.rules.setObjectName('rules')
        self.rules.setWordWrap(True)    

        self.button_rules = QPushButton('Правила')
        self.button_rules.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open('https://ru.wwbm.com/rules'))
        self.button_rules.setFixedSize(300,50)


        self.button_start = QPushButton('Почати', clicked=self._start)  
        self.button_start.setFixedSize(300,50)
        
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.lineH1 = QHBoxLayout()
        lineH2 = QHBoxLayout()
        lineH3 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lineH1.addWidget(self.question, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        lineH2.addWidget(self.rules)
        lineH3.addWidget(self.button_rules, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        lineH3.addWidget(self.button_start, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.lineH1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.rules, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.layout.addLayout(lineH3)
        
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_timer)

        self.windowGroup = WindowGroup()

        self.windowGroup.rbtn_1.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.windowGroup.rbtn_2.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.windowGroup.rbtn_3.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.windowGroup.rbtn_4.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.list_rbtn = [
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_1,
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_2,
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_3,
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_4,
        ] 
        self.correct_answer = '<h1 style="color: #4E9F3D;">Це вірна відповідь!</h1>'
        self.wrong_answer = '<h1 style="color: #DA0037;">Це НЕ вірна відповідь!</h1>'

        self.windowGroup.hint_5050.clicked.connect(self.clicked_5050)
        self.windowGroup.hint_audience.clicked.connect(self.clicked_audience)

    def on_clicked(self):
        self.windowGroup.setEnabled(False)
        sender = self.sender()  
        self.sender_click = sender
# !!!
# !!!        if sender.text() in self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons:
# +++ vvv
        if sender.text() == self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[
            self.windowGroup.current_question][self.windowGroup.current_question_index]:
            sender.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                f'{self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question][self.windowGroup.current_question_index]} \
                {self.correct_answer}' 
            )                 
        else:
            sender.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;") 
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                f'{self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question][self.windowGroup.current_question_index]} \
                {self.wrong_answer}' 
            )         
            self.windowGroup.current_question = self.windowGroup.quantity_questions
            self.num = 3    
        self.windowGroup.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
# +++ ^^^
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.third)  

    def set_stylesheet(self):  
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel, QPushButton {
                font-size: 20pt;
            }
            #rules { 
                background-color: #ccffbd;
            }
            #windowgroup > QLabel { 
                font-size: 11pt;
            }
            #windowgroup > QGroupBox { 
                background-color: #a44500;
                font-size: 20pt;
                width: 620px; height: 49px;
            }
            QPushButton {
                background-color: #D98C00;
                font-size: 34px;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: #0082fc;
                border: 2px solid #FFA6D5;
            }
            #centralWidget {
                background-image: url(first.jpg);
            }
            #window_audience {
                backround-image: url(first.jpg);
            }
            """) 
        
    def update_timer(self):        
        self.question.setText(f'<h1 style="color: rgb(250, 55, 55);">{self.num}</h1>')
        if self.num == 0:
            self.timer.stop()
            
            self.set_stylesheet()                 

            self.question.setPixmap(QPixmap("million.png"))
            self.num = 3
            self.rules.hide()
            self.button_start.hide()
            self.button_rules.hide()
            self.layout.addWidget(self.windowGroup, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

            self.lineH1.insertStretch(0)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(1, self.windowGroup.hint_5050)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(2)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(3, self.windowGroup.hint_audience)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(4)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(-1)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(-1, self.windowGroup.hint_expert)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(-1)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(-1, self.windowGroup.hint_switch)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(-1)

            return            
        self.num -= 1        

    def _start(self):
        self.timer.start(1000)     

    def third(self):
        self.windowGroup.setEnabled(True)  
# ???
# ???        self.windowGroup.hint_5050.setEnabled(False)      
        
        if self.windowGroup.current_question + 1 < self.windowGroup.quantity_questions:

            self.windowGroup.current_question += 1
# !!!            
#            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
#                self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question])
# +++ vvv
            self.windowGroup.current_question_text = random.choices(
                self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question])[0]
            self.windowGroup.current_question_index = self.windowGroup.list_questions[
                self.windowGroup.current_question].index(self.windowGroup.current_question_text)
            # print(f'\n{self.windowGroup.current_question_index} == {self.windowGroup.current_question_text}\n') #
        
#            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
#                self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question])
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                self.windowGroup.current_question_text)
            
#            self.windowGroup.rbtn_1.setText(
#                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][0])
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_1.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[
                    self.windowGroup.current_question][self.windowGroup.current_question_index][0])                
                
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_2.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[
                    self.windowGroup.current_question][self.windowGroup.current_question_index][2])
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_3.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[
                    self.windowGroup.current_question][self.windowGroup.current_question_index][1])
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_4.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[
                    self.windowGroup.current_question][self.windowGroup.current_question_index][3])                
# +++ ^^^            
            self.set_stylesheet()            
        else:
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                '<h1 style="color: #FFDD93;">Гру закінчено, дякуємо за участь!</h1>'
            )             
            self.windowGroup.setEnabled(False)
            self.sender_click.setStyleSheet(
                "background-color: #D98C00; width: 780px; height: 49px;")
            self.set_stylesheet() 
            
        for rbtn in self.list_rbtn:    
            rbtn.setEnabled(True)
            rbtn.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton {
                    background-color: #D98C00; 
                    width: 620px; height: 49px;
                }
                QPushButton:hover {
                    background-color: #0082fc;
                    border: 2px solid #FFA6D5;
                }
            """)
            
        self.windowGroup.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)   
# !!!
    def clicked_5050(self):
        self.windowGroup.hint_5050.setEnabled(False)
        
        current_question = self.windowGroup.current_question
# !!!
# +++ vvv       
#        list_yes_buttons = self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[current_question]
        list_yes_buttons = self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[
            current_question][self.windowGroup.current_question_index]
        
        list_5050 = [list_yes_buttons,]
       
        not_buttons = self.windowGroup.list_buttons[current_question][self.windowGroup.current_question_index]
        not_buttons.remove(list_yes_buttons)
        not_buttons = random.choices(not_buttons)
# +++ ^^^
        list_5050.append(not_buttons[0])
        
        for rbtn in self.list_rbtn:
            if rbtn.text() in list_5050:
                pass
            else:
                rbtn.setEnabled(False)

        
    def clicked_audience(self):
        self.windowGroup.hint_audience.setEnabled(False)
# +++
#        litter_yes = self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[
#            self.windowGroup.current_question][0]
# +++ !!!
        litter_yes = self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[
            self.windowGroup.current_question][self.windowGroup.current_question_index][0]
# +++ ^^^            
        img = self.dict_audience_img[litter_yes]
        
        self.audience_messageBox(img)
        
    def audience_messageBox(self, img):        
        window_audience = QMessageBox(self)
        window_audience.setWindowIcon(QIcon("audience_normal.png"))
        window_audience.setWindowTitle('Допомога зали') 

        window_audience.setIconPixmap(
            QPixmap(img).scaled(700, 700, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            )
        window_audience.exec_()   
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet("""
        QLabel {
            font-size: 20pt;
        }
        QPushButton { 
            font-size: 20pt;
            background-color: #ff8000;
        }
        #centralWidget {
            background-image: url(first.jpg);
        }
        #centeralMessage {
            backround-image: url(first.jpg);
        }
    """)
    w = MainWindow()          
    w.setWindowTitle('Million')  
    w.resize(1700, 770)
    w.move(125, 110)
    w.show()                           
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Путь, который вы избрали -  тупиковый. Так и хочется спросить -  у кого вы его содрали?  Сегодня вы хотите добавить 15 вопросов, а завтра захотите добавить еще 25 да 6 удалить. И что? Снова лезть в код, переписывать логику, вносить десяток ошибок и четыре дня их потом искать?

Давать советы о том, как исправить явно "бракованное" изделие (программу), работоспособность которого будет всегда под огромным вопросом  даже не хочется. А вот совет дам:  не маяться дурью, а один раз переписать программу так, что-бы потом не было мучительно больно изменять запятую в вопросе. А именно - разделить логику, данные и интерфейс. Отдельно написать часть, которая бы извлекала из базы вопросов нужное количество и в нужном порядке вопросы. Отдельно обернуть  в API свое хранилище вопросов и ответов. И ко всему этому приладить пользовательский интерфейс, который так-же можно было при желании изменить.

И глобальный совет -  не учите программирование по видосикам и обрывками каких-то статеек из интернета. Лучше потратьте время на то, что бы взять нормальный учебник по основам программирования и детально, последовательно его изучите. Будет и полезнее, и эффективнее и в конечном итоге быстрее.